# How does Rust automatically generate JSON based on changes to a struct?

Tags: json, rust, serde

I'm writing a game server in rust. It is necessary to modify the structure and deliver the changed part to the client. How to automate this process?

I tried copying this structure and comparing it, but it was too expensive. I also tried DerefMut to mark changed fields, but it was not convenient enough.

```
let mut sam = Human {
    name: "114514".to_string(),
    age: 114514
};
sam.age = 114515;
assert_eq!(sam.diff_json(), json!{"age":114515});
```

Comment: Please share some code for the cases you already tried and describing what was wrong with it. What do you mean by 'not convenient enough'?

Comment: The way a lot of game engines work is by evaluating the current state and inputs and generating a series of _commands_ which represent the change in state. After completely evaluating the state+input, these commands are applied one by one to update the game state. Compared to update the state as the state is evaluated, this solves a few issues. In Rust, it solves can solve borrowing issues. It also solves the issue where an earlier update within the same frame can alter how another section is interpreted.

Comment: If you design your engine this way, you can simply serialize the applicable parts of the commands to each client that needs that particular update.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is not a simple generic way of doing this if you are looking for performance. You could do this by deserializing to a `serde_json::Value` and comparing equality of fields, but this will likely be more expensive than whatever you are doing currently. Here is a quick example of what that would look like ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=87021046725a1bbdfe7bffde1ea82184)).

```rust
pub fn collect_changes<T>(initial: &T, modified: &T) -> Result<Value, serde_json::Error>
where
    T: Serialize + for<'de> Deserialize<'de>,
{
    let initial_value = serde_json::to_value(initial)?;
    let modified_value = serde_json::to_value(modified)?;

    match extract_changes(&initial_value, modified_value) {
        None => Ok(placeholder_for(&initial_value)),
        Some(changes) => Ok(changes),
    }
}

pub fn extract_changes(a: &Value, b: Value) -> Option<Value> {
    match (a, b) {
        (Value::Null, Value::Null) => None,
        (Value::Bool(x), Value::Bool(y)) => (x != &y).then(|| Value::Bool(y)),
        (Value::Number(x), Value::Number(y)) => (x != &y).then(|| Value::Number(y)),
        (Value::String(x), Value::String(y)) => (x != &y).then(|| Value::String(y)),
        (Value::Array(x), Value::Array(y)) => {
            let mut changes = Vec::with_capacity(y.len());
            let mut modified_values = y.into_iter();

            for (initial, modified) in x.iter().zip(&mut modified_values) {
                match extract_changes(initial, modified) {
                    None => changes.push(placeholder_for(initial)),
                    Some(change) => changes.push(change),
                }
            }

            changes.extend(modified_values);
            (x != &changes).then(|| Value::Array(changes))
        }
        (Value::Object(x), Value::Object(y)) => {
            let mut changes = Map::new();

            for (key, value) in y {
                match x.get(&key) {
                    None => {
                        changes.insert(key, value);
                    }
                    Some(initial) => {
                        if let Some(change) = extract_changes(initial, value) {
                            changes.insert(key, change);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            (!changes.is_empty()).then(|| Value::Object(changes))
        }
        (_, new) => Some(new),
    }
}

fn placeholder_for(x: &Value) -> Value {
    match x {
        Value::Null => Value::Null,
        Value::Bool(x) => Value::Bool(*x),
        Value::Number(x) => Value::Number(x.to_owned()),
        Value::String(x) => Value::String(x.to_owned()),
        Value::Array(items) => Value::Array(items.iter().map(placeholder_for).collect()),
        Value::Object(_) => Value::Object(Map::new()),
    }
}
```

What I would recommend doing instead is something similar to what @cdhowie is suggesting. Instead of searching for differences, make a list of the specific ways in which your data is modified. For each of those items, you can make an event that describes how the state changes. You can then send these events as needed instead of always checking every field.

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum UpdateHumanEvent {
    Rename(String),
    IncreaseAge(u32),
}
```

If performance is an issue, there are a few other things you can do as well. First off is the obligatory make sure you run your code with `--release`. The compiler wont attempt to perform any optimizations unless you tell it to do so.

Next, consider using a different serialization format. JSON is a great format since it is human readable, but I'm not sure if you need that feature. Maybe try using `serde_bare` instead to serialize/deserialize data that will be sent over the network. Keep in mind though that this format is not self describing, so you could run into issues if you change the structure of an event then attempt to send data between different versions of your application.

Additionally, you could try using `Cow<'de, str>` instead of `String`. Allocating a string for every deserialize call can be expensive if you do it a lot. By using a `Cow` instead, you give the deserializer the option to give you a reference to the data source instead of allocating a new buffer and copying the data. Another option would be to use `Deserialize::deserialize_in_place` when deserializing, but you need to enable the feature `deserialize_in_place` on `serde_derive` to get it to actually start deriving this function. This can help, but your mileage will vary depending on the data you are working with so it is not appropriate for all usecases.